# How to passing variable into another function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need some help with JQuery.
In my site I have a button that repeats in a layout. I decided to differentiate them by adding a class to each of them with a number with this code below which works very well.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // each button in the Machine loop get a unique CLASS 
  jQuery(".rv_button").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).addClass("item" + (i + 1));
    var its = ("item" + (i + 1));
    console.log("." + its);
  });
});
```

This button will be used to make appear or disappear a section that I also decided to differentiate them by adding a class to each of them with a number with this code below which works very well.

```
jQuery(".reveal").each(function(f) {
  // each section in the Machine loop get a unique CLASS 
  jQuery(this).addClass("rive" + (f + 1));
  var id = ("rive" + (f + 1)); // each section in the Machine loop get a unique CLASS 
  console.log("." + id);
});
```

I would like to create a code which has the function of when I click on item1 -> rive1 appears and disappears etc ...
here is my test code which does not work because I do not know how to include the variable included previously.

```
var id;
var its;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // The section is HIDE with the new class
  jQuery("." + id).hide();
  // The click function on the new button class
  jQuery("." + its).click(function(e) {
    // when i click on the new class button, the section appaear or desapear.
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("." + id).slideToggle();
    jQuery("." + its).toggleClass('opened closed');
  });
});
```

Any idea on how to passing the Variable into the last function ?

thanks all !

This the entire code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // each button in the Machine loop get a unique CLASS 
  jQuery(".rv_button").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).addClass("item" + (i + 1));
    var its = ("item" + (i + 1));
    console.log("." + its);

  });

  jQuery(".reveal").each(function(f) {
    // each section in the Machine loop get a unique CLASS 
    jQuery(this).addClass("rive" + (f + 1));
    var id = ("rive" + (f + 1)); // each section in the Machine loop get a unique CLASS 
    console.log("." + id);
  });

  var id;
  var its;

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // The section is HIDE with the new class
    jQuery("." + id).hide();
    // The click function on the new button class
    jQuery("." + its).click(function(e) {
      // when i click on the new class button, the section appaear or desapear.
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery("." + id).slideToggle();
      jQuery("." + its).toggleClass('opened closed');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: No need to add different class names. Educate yourself on `jQuery(this)` inside your handlers.

Comment: And please, for the sake of sanity, please format your code! many times we skip right over questions that have code formatted in such a poor way. Why take the time to answer if you don't want to take the time to do something so simple.

Comment: Here's how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/k83rcd4o/ (the main issue with your code is that you're adding classes like rive1 and rive2 but not making any attempt to read back the number; it's a bad approach though, and not necessary)

Comment: Consider using only one `jQuery(document).ready` put all the functions in there